# Is there any consequences for cancelling an Oracle Gather Stats job?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, database-administration

For example, if I manually execute a gather stats job on my Oracle database. And I kill this session, hence the stats doesn’t complete, is there any rollback? Or are the stats considered usable?

Comment: You can check it by yourself in `all_tab_cols` and `all_tab_statistics` in columns `last_analyzed` and `stale_stats`.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no consequence, in the sense that your DB will still work, no errors given. But, if your were gathering stats for a whole schema, maybe some objects will have their stats updated while others not, and so may give you some surprises in execution plans.